# How to put alternating elements in a column-based layout from an array data model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

There is a dynamic array in the `$scope`, and three columns in the HTML template. Elements in the array are needed to be rendered in HTML like this:

```html
<div class="first-column">
  <div><!--element of (index + 3) % 3 === 0 will be placed here--></div>
</div>

<div class="second-column">
  <div><!--element of (index + 3) % 3 === 1 will be placed here--></div>
</div>

<div class="third-column">
  <div><!--element of (index + 3) % 3 === 2 will be placed here--></div>
</div>
```

Note, the three columns only appear once. Each element will be placed in certain column, according to its index matching the expression.

Of course, I can use three `ng-repeat` declarations to fulfill it, but for performance considerations, I want to make it work just using a single `ng-repeat`.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: i just stumbled upon the *exact same issue*. perhaps nested `ng-repeat`s with inner `$index` references?

Comment: yup, that does the trick. see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested `ng-repeat`s to condition each item within the columns; assuming such a model:

```js
columns: [1,2,3],
items: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

your view will look like this:

```html
<div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat="c in columns">
    <h1>Column {{ (outerIndex = $index) && c || c }}</h1>
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="i in items" 
                      ng-if="$index % columns.length === outerIndex">
        <!-- whatever -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Note how we inject a new variable (`outerIndex`) into the outer loop scope, to be used in conjunction with the inner loop's `$index` for the alternating conditional.

Click the big demo button below to see it in action (we rely here on bootstrap-css, just for the sake of demonstrating columns in the layout).

---

**TL;DR**, Gimmi tha demo!

[<kbd>**Big Demo Button**</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/bNR7eAFUbq7Wi6lk7KAp?p=preview)

Comment: this is a bit quick and dirty, i'll be back soon to refactor, and extract a generic a directive out of this. this should get you started, though.

Comment: thanks for answering and editing:). Your answer works but it actually still loops the `items` array entirely 3 times, so there is still a potential performance issue. I solved it by using 3 array, and it's tricky as well. I will post it as an answer later. I'll keep searching for a better way.

Comment: The performance bottleneck is in **mutating the DOM**, not in looping the data. We're using conditionals (`ng-if`) to tackle that very issue, so no penalties here. It is however always better to model your data correctly in the first place, so perhaps you can move from three arrays to a matrix (!), which best describes tabular data.

Comment: It makes senses and is acceptable...I accepted it as a solution. But I am still wondering if there is a better way avoiding looping it 3 times.

Comment: Yes, using three arrays is actually hard code. Matrix is more scalable an flexible. Thanks for it again.

Comment: Well, when using a flat array as the data model, **any underlying implementation** will also have to loop that structure (the array) `n` times (where `n = columns.length`) to get the items alternating according to a specified column... so I don't see a way out of that pit. At least it's a **sorted** data-structure so we don't have to mess with sorting as well (*kind of a pet on the back*). Anyways don't even worry about the performance of looping, it's negligible.